# failed to restart samba after modifying smb.conf

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 server and I installed samba by using

```
apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba
```

after that my another vm can successfully use `smbclient` to build connection and everything works but after I add the following lines,

```
[share]
path = /samba/share
browseable = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

trying to add a share folder in `smb.conf` and restart samba using

```
/etc/init.d/samba restart
```

it failed to restart and I got the following:

[image: info]

Why is this bothering NetBIOS? or it is actually about other stuff?

Comment: You can test your `smb.conf` file with the command `testparm`.

Comment: the only warning from testparm is ' "syslog" option is deprecated '
, but isn't that because that parameter will be removed in the future?
other stuff looks fine , 
and it do print the definition of my share folder, like this


[share]

   path = /samba/share

   read only = no

   guest ok = yes

       (sorry for the type setting)

Comment: OK, maybe it's a rights problem – do users of the group `nogroup` have rights in your share folder?

Comment: What does `smbcontrol all reload-config` output?

Comment: I tried chmod 777 the share folder, it works lol, thanks a lot !!!
by the way,  is there other "proper" method to give rights?

Comment: `smbcontrol all reload-config`   prints nothing

Comment: `chmod` is the proper tool to set the rights. The thing is that the user rights in your share have to be the same as in the file system.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo systemctl -l status nmbd.service` like the error messages suggests? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the rights in you share folder correctly with

```
chmod 777 /samba/share
```

and reload `smb.conf` with

```
smbcontrol all reload-config
```